# CSS3 Javascript Library for Gradients?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gradient

Is there a way to create gradients using CSS3 and then - by using javascript (or server side?) - I will be able to support IE or other unsupported browsers? I mean - the js library will convert the gradient to PNG background..

Is there something like that?

Comment: Does the png have to be programmatically constructed via JavaScript from a CSS3 gradient?  Or are you just looking for ways to create .PNG files that happen to be gradients?

Comment: I want them to be programmatically constructed via JS? If this is possible then it could save a lot of cross-browser work, this is why I am asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to convert CSS gradients to PNG, I assume you'll have to construct them beforehand and display the correct background depending on the user-agent (i.e. PNG background for older browsers).
However, if you're looking for a way to create gradients in CSS3 for all browsers, try this website:
http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/
It will give you the recipe for gradients on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible using the  URL(data...) And passing base64 bitmap data defining your png on the fly as it were. See http://www.patternify.com/ for an example of this technique in action

Answer (score 0):

I found also this cool tool:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It gives you the ability to customize a gradient (with a lot of features) and it supports all browsers! Cool!